# NestJS/TypeORM: I have 2 connections, how can I be sure to use the current one?

Tags: nestjs, datasource, typeorm, multi-tenant, row-level-security

I'm working on a setup to have a **NestJS app with TypeORM**, connected to a **postgresql multi-tenant database** with 1 schema and **Row Level Security** (RLS) policies on tenanted tables.

I have different kinds of users who can connect to the DB and one of them is restricted by the RLS policies, ensuring it can only access the values related to its tenantId.

Following this idea, I have 2 connections defined in my app and I named them as NestJS doc [suggests](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases).

If I get it right, when you define 2 named connections, you have to tell NestJS the name of the connection you want to use every time you need them.

The issue is that my connection will depend on the user who will use the app: most will be restricted by the RLS policies but some with admin rights won't be. So for a lot of services, I cannot tell in advance which kind of connection I will need.

- Is there a way to pass the current connection to a service?
- Or should I dynamically create just 1 connection based on the type of user who wants to use the app?

Just a disclaimer: I'm still green in the development and definitely a newbie in multi-tenancy so sorry if my questions seem too simplistic (oh and also, I'm French so I hope I'm clear :) Thank you!